# Regarding Congruence Subgroups and Normal Subgroups of Finite Index of the Modular Group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ($SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$)

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, quotient-group, modular-group

Let $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ($SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$) be the modular group.

It is too easy to see that every congruence subgroup of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ($SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$) is a normal subgroup of finite index.

The question is whether the converse is also ture, i.e., is every normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ($SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$) congruence subgroup of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ($SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$)?

Comment: What is a "congruence subgroup" to you? And no see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf p.10-11

Comment: @reuns I edited the question

Comment: What is a "congruence subgroup" ?

Comment: @reuns https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup

Comment: Does it look normal ?

Comment: I think, you are confusing congruence subgroups and **principal** congruence subgroups $\Gamma(n)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes

Comment: @MoisheKohan is every normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group congruence subgroup, i.e., contains a principle congruence subgroup?

Comment: No, this is the failure of the Congruence Subgroup Property, which is discussed in the wikipedia page that you linked. (Also, note that for every finite index subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ there exists a further finite index subgroup $N< H$ such that $N$ is normal in $G$.)